# HTTP To HTTPS sitemap issues

Tags: google-search-console, php, sitemap, robots.txt

Today I moved my site from HTTP to HTTPs successfully.

Code I used:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on"){
    if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli'){
    }
    else{
            $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $new_url = "https://" . $host . $request_uri;
            header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
            header( "Location: $new_url" );
            exit;
    }
}
```

Issue that I'm facing:

When I try to submit my sitemap (`https://example.com/support/ssl_siteMap_worksheet.xml`):

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/worksheet/rebus/maths/</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-10-24</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/worksheet/rebus/kids/</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-10-24</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/worksheet/rebus/medium/</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-10-24</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/worksheet/rebus/hard/</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-10-24</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/worksheet/rebus/</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-10-24</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

It's giving me the following error:

> Warnings, URL blocked by robots.txt, Sitemap contains URLs which are blocked by robots.txt.

Here is my `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent:    *
Disallow:   /smarty/*
Disallow:   /images/*
Disallow:   /images/
Disallow:   /css/*
Disallow:   /css/
Disallow:   /minify/
Disallow:   /minify/*
Disallow:   default.php

#Begin Attracta SEO Tools Sitemap. Do not remove
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_interview_allpuzzles.xml
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_interview_compuzzles.xml
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_interview_list.xml
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_interview_process.xml
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_interview_tech.xml
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_list_puzzles_riddles.xml
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_main_1.xml
sitemap: http://example.com/support/siteMap_main_2.xml
sitemap: https://example.com/support/ssl_siteMap_worksheet.xml
#End Attracta SEO Tools Sitemap. Do not remove
```

Note: If I change URLs in sitemap from HTTPS to HTTP, it's working.
i.e If the change from

```
https://example.com/worksheet/rebus/maths/
```

to

```
http://example.com/worksheet/rebus/maths/
```

Sitemap submission is not showing an error.

Comment: Are you submitting the sitemap to the HTTPS property in GSC?

Comment: Can you show us both version(http and https) of your robots.txt? I don't know why you're mixing(http and https) sitemap into robots.txt, just keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face the similar issue and you it was resolved when I contact the service provider i.e HostGator/Bluehost (not sure which one) and after a day it got resolved.

Comment: Can you say *how* they resolved it?

Comment: @JohnConde they were blocking at nginx level